# SQL select multiple max date for each different zone_id where account could be the same

Tags: sql

Using following Query

```
SELECT     evhist_XPK.event_date, evhist_XPK.zone_id, system.account
FROM         evhist_XPK INNER JOIN
             system ON evhist_XPK.system_no = system.system_no INNER JOIN
             site ON system.site_no = site.site_no INNER JOIN
             event ON event.event_id=evhist_XPK.event_id
WHERE        (evhist_XPK.event_id = '7381')  AND (evhist_XPK.event_date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0))
ORDER BY system.account
```

I get this

```
event_date          zone_id     account   
2019-01-22 07:10:10.607     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-22 07:10:12.637     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-23 08:44:50.737     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-23 08:44:50.907     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-23 21:01:09.523     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-23 21:01:09.540     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-24 06:58:44.107     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-24 06:58:46.137     10           V0137C4 
2019-01-25 07:24:07.000     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-25 07:24:07.080     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-28 06:54:53.507     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-28 06:54:53.600     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-29 07:45:10.520     9           V0137C4 
2019-01-29 07:45:12.597     10          V0137C4 
2019-01-29 07:45:21.520     12          V013708 
2019-01-29 07:45:32.597     13          V013708 
2019-01-29 07:45:35.520     11          V013708 
2019-01-29 07:45:38.620     11          V013708
```

But I need to get these below records with the max datetime of each zone_id of different account

```
2019-01-29 07:45:10.520 9   V0137C4 
2019-01-29 07:45:12.597 10  V0137C4 
2019-01-29 07:45:21.520 12  V013708 
2019-01-29 07:45:32.597 13  V013708 
2019-01-29 07:45:38.620 11  V013708
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  For instance:

```
WITH q as (<your query here without the order by>)
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT q.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY zone_id, account ORDER BY event_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM q
     ) q
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY account;
```

Or a fun way is simply to add:

Comment: Gordon, simply Wonderful !!! Thanks a lot for your prompt and right reply, regards

Comment: @Claudio Accept the answer if the solution worked for you please

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following, which is simpler:

```
SELECT MAX(event_date), zone_id, account
FROM
(
   --Your query
   SELECT evhist_XPK.event_date, evhist_XPK.zone_id, system.account
   FROM evhist_XPK 
   INNER JOIN system 
      ON evhist_XPK.system_no = system.system_no 
   INNER JOIN site 
      ON system.site_no = site.site_no 
   INNER JOIN event 
      ON event.event_id = evhist_XPK.event_id
   WHERE (evhist_XPK.event_id = '7381')  
   AND (evhist_XPK.event_date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0))
) t1
GROUP BY zone_id, account
ORDER BY account;
```